# Low Alphabet and ajax

Tags: ajax, low-alphabet

I would to know if it's possible to use ajax with Low Alphabet. 
I did a alphabet glossary,  each time the letter is clicked,  the whole page is loaded.  How to use ajax to reload only the Low Alphabet window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has little to do with the workings of Low Alphabet itself. Rather, it's a JavaScript question, along with some smart templating to allow for proper ajax requests. Steps to take:

- Create 2 templates: 1 for the full page, and 1 just for the low_alphabet:entries tag.
- Embed the latter in the former, but make sure the second template is also approachable directly.
- In the main template, add the AZ-List tag, with regular links.
- With JS, add an onclick event to those links, triggering an Ajax call to embedded template, and add the output to the main page.

The same principle could be applied to any EE content that needs to be called via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot Low, i didn't know exatly what to do. Yours steps helps me to build a dynamic glossary.